# Gulpjs watch tasks only seems to work with globs

Tags: gulp

Is it required for a gulp watch task to use globs if only an absolute file path should be watched?

Here is my example:

```
const files = {
  style: path.join(paths.config, 'style.css')
};

const globs = {
  style: path.join(paths.config, '/**/', 'style.css')
};

function assets() {return gulp.src([...]).pipe(gulp.dest(...);}

gulp.task('watch-glob', function() {
  gulp.watch(glob.style, assets);
}

gulp.task('watch-file', function() {
  gulp.watch(files.style, assets);
}
```

The first watch tasks works fine and the second works only once.